# Convert dynamic DOM structure to JSON

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

How can convert below DOM  to JSON array which will have many more leafs in thefuture . I have tried a lot but didn't got any solution. I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7993066/convert-dom-structrue-to-json) but it is not possible in my case.

**HTML Code**

```
 <ul id="org1">
        <li>
            Main
            <ul data-self="1">
                <li data-self="2" data-parent="1">A
                    <ul data-self="2">
                        <li data-self="5" data-parent="2">A1</li>
                        <li data-self="6" data-parent="2">A2</li>
                        <li data-self="7" data-parent="2">A3</li>
                        <li data-self="8" data-parent="2">A4</li>
                        <li data-self="9" data-parent="2">A5</li>
                        <li data-self="10" data-parent="2">A6</li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li data-self="3" data-parent="1">B
                    <ul data-self="3">
                        <li data-self="11" data-parent="3">B1</li>
                        <li data-self="12" data-parent="3">B2</li>
                        <li data-self="13" data-parent="3">B3</li>
                        <li data-self="14" data-parent="3">B4</li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>
```

**JSON Required is**

```
{
  1:{
      2:{5,6,7,8,9,10},
      3:{11,12,13,14} 
    }
}
```

**Script**

```
function recursive(dis)
    {
        $(this).find(' > ul ').each(function(){
                params[$(this).attr('data-self')]=[];
                var i=0;
                $(this).find('li').each(function(){

                     if($(this).has('ul'))
                     {
                        params[$(this).attr('data-parent')][i++]=rec(this);
                     }else
                     {
                        params[$(this).attr('data-parent')][i++]=$(this).attr('data-self');
                     }

                });
            });

    }
recursive('#org1');
console.log(params);
```

Comment: at least show us _what_ you have tried...

Comment: what you have tried just show the code. We didn't type all the code and get answer for you it is not possible

Comment: one minute posting code

Comment: please check code updated

Comment: `{
  1:{
      2:{5,6,7,8,9,10},
      3:{11,12,13,14} 
    }
}` is not JSON. It isn't even JavaScript.

Comment: @Quentin I'm guessing the OP means `{ 1:{ 2:[5,6,7,8,9,10], 3:[11,12,13,14] } }` which is valid JavaScript

Comment: yes @Quentin here matter about logic ,  I just posted .

Answer (score 1):

I would prefer something like the following. The 2 changes in the HTML you need to make are:

1) Add a class to your `ul` such as `<ul data-self="2" class="nodes">`. 2) Add a class to the wrapper `ul` such as `<ul data-self="1" class="parent">`.

```js
var json = {};
$("#org1").find("ul.parent").each(function() {
    
    var $this = $(this);
    json[$this.data("self")] = {};
    var $nodes = $this.find("ul.nodes");
    $nodes.each(function() {
        var children = $(this).find("li").map(function() {
            return $(this).data("self")
        }).get();
        json[$this.data("self")][$(this).data("self")] = children;
    });
});

alert (JSON.stringify(json));
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul id="org1">
    <li>
        Main
        <ul data-self="1" class="parent">
            <li data-self="2" data-parent="1">A
                <ul data-self="2" class="nodes">
                    <li data-self="5" data-parent="2">A1</li>
                    <li data-self="6" data-parent="2">A2</li>
                    <li data-self="7" data-parent="2">A3</li>
                    <li data-self="8" data-parent="2">A4</li>
                    <li data-self="9" data-parent="2">A5</li>
                    <li data-self="10" data-parent="2">A6</li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li data-self="3" data-parent="1">B
                <ul data-self="3" class="nodes">
                    <li data-self="11" data-parent="3">B1</li>
                    <li data-self="12" data-parent="3">B2</li>
                    <li data-self="13" data-parent="3">B3</li>
                    <li data-self="14" data-parent="3">B4</li>
                </ul>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: A change to the HTML is not needed

Comment: @JuanMendes sure, that was just my preference.

Comment: Thanks , You suggested very good solution but i think it may not work if there are two more <ul>'s added at leaf <li> , Bcoz we are using class "nodes" it may recursively collect all child <ul>s also got my point? LShetty

Comment: yes you have added  more childs  at second level can you add under "Main->A->A1-><ul class='nodes'><li>A11</li></ul>"

Comment: Sure, my answer is purely based on your question and the example you've posted plus assumed extension of structure. One cannot answer based on all levels of nesting you may have in your DOM structure. Adapt the code to suit your needs, and good luck ;)